# jQuery wrap the selected markup with proper closing and ending tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my markup like this.

```
<ul class="language-dropdown">
  <li class="lang-switch language_en current_lang ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/en.png" alt="en">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_es ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/es.png" alt="es">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_de ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/de.png" alt="de">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_ja ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/ja.png" alt="ja">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now here you can see I have a li which has class current_lang. Now I want that jquery will find the class with the markup and the selected html markup will be added as a wrap for the total ul. I mean to say the output should be like this

```
<li class="lang-switch language_en current_lang ">
  <a href="#"><img src="res/flags/en.png" alt="en"></a>
<ul class="language-dropdown">
  <li class="lang-switch language_en current_lang ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/en.png" alt="en">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_es ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/es.png" alt="es">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_de ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/de.png" alt="de">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_ja ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/ja.png" alt="ja">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
```

So that I can get the current_lang at the top and all the list as dropdown. So to do I just made my code like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var Current = jQuery('li.current_lang').prop('outerHTML');
  jQuery('ul.language-dropdown').wrapAll(Current);
});
```

But this one is doing the wrap like this

```
<li class="lang-switch language_en current_lang ">
  <a href="#">
  <img src="res/flags/en.png" alt="en">
<ul class="language-dropdown">
  <li class="lang-switch language_en current_lang ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/en.png" alt="en">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_es ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/es.png" alt="es">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_de ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/de.png" alt="de">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="lang-switch language_ja ">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="res/flags/ja.png" alt="ja">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
</img>
</a>
</li>
```

So can someone kindly tell me what is the easy way to get it in a proper way. Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: The expected output is an invalid markup.

Answer (score 0):

After closing the tags properly, your code works and got the required output. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/baga143/WX3za/).

```
<ul class="language-dropdown">
    <li class="lang-switch language_en current_lang "><a href="#">
        <img src="res/flags/en.png" alt="en" />
    </a></li>
    <li class="lang-switch language_es "><a href="#">
        <img src="res/flags/es.png" alt="es" />
    </a></li>
    <li class="lang-switch language_de "><a href="#">
        <img src="res/flags/de.png" alt="de" />
    </a></li>
    <li class="lang-switch language_ja "><a href="#">
        <img src="res/flags/ja.png" alt="ja" />
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

Please add a comment if this is not the output you are looking for.